# Error when try make new spreadsheet from array

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Im trying to make new worksheet from data array

```
 $tempspreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
          $i=1; foreach($arr_excel_temp as $Temporary) {
              $tempspreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A'. $i, $Temporary)
                        ->setCellValue('B'. $i, $Temporary);
              $i++;
          }
```

'A'.$i is it right?

Comment: And what's the error??

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: Cell/DefaultValueBinder.php

Line Number: 56

Comment: And line 56 is...|?

Comment: i think error bcause $temporary is array 2D..

Comment: Can you put sample data for $arr_excel_temp